# Parametrizing output of a select statement PSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-8.3

I am on a version of postgresql that was built off 8.3.  I run a ton of queries based on specific Ip address and wanted to create a function that I can pass the  IP address as a parameter similar to:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION features.src_forensics(text)     
RETURNS SETOF rows as
$$

select src, action,
count(distinct date_trunc('day', receive_time) ) n_activeDay,
count(distinct source_IP) n_src,
count(distinct source_IP) / count(distinct date_trunc('day', receive_time)) n_src_per_day,
sum(bytes) as total_bytes,
min(receive_time) minTime,
max(receive_time) maxTime
from  table
where src = $1 
group by src, action ;
```

$$ LANGUAGE sql;

The problem is the above query does not return the output of the select statement in a table format I am used to.  How do I get the script I wrote above to behave like the select statement below if I pass 10.10.0.1 as the IP address input to the function?

```
select src, action,
count(distinct date_trunc('day', receive_time) ) n_activeDay,
count(distinct source_IP) n_src,
count(distinct source_IP) / count(distinct date_trunc('day', receive_time)) n_src_per_day,
sum(bytes) as total_bytes,
min(receive_time) minTime,
max(receive_time) maxTime
from  table
where src = '10.10.0.1'
group by src, action;
```

Comment: What "table format" is being outputted? Output format is highly dependent on what client you're using and how that client is configured.  In general, I think we need more information about what exactly it is doing that is unusual. I will go ahead and mention - I'm not sure if `RETURNS SETOF rows` will change functionality.  It obviously saves ok, but I've normally seen `RETURNS SETOF record`.  You might try changing it and see if that gets you more what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I generally do this when returning an arbitrary set of columns:

```
RETURNS TABLE(
    src             text,
    action          text,
    n_activeDay     bigint,
    n_src           bigint,
    n_src_per_day   bigint,
    total_bytes     bigint,
    minTime         timestamptz,
    maxTime         timestamptz
) AS
```

It may be possible to change how you query the function, if you prefer leaving the definition unchanged:

```
select * from features.src_forensics("a") AS f(
        src             text,
        action          text,
        n_activeDay     bigint,
        n_src           bigint,
        n_src_per_day   bigint,
        total_bytes     bigint,
        minTime         timestamptz,
        maxTime         timestamptz
    );
```